HTTPS timeout/site won't load. HTTP works
Have 'mydomain.com' hosted by GoDaddy 'with multiple CNAMEs, ex: 'one.mydomain.com', 'two.mydomain.com'.
I have a wildcard SSL certificate from GoDaddy  installed in IIS and setup site bindings. Every site loads using HTTP on port 80, but times out when loading a site with HTTPS:// through multiple browsers.
I have confirmed that the  certificates are installed and selected, site bindings are correct, and port 443 is open on firewall.
What else could I be missing?






https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html You can get started from there.

While this seems fine, it’s doesn’t confirm that port 443 connections are actually allowed on firewalls. Try accessing it from the machine itself (ex by using curl or OpenSSL s_client) to check if you can get a certificate response to begin with. Failing that, ping the port using for example “nc -z”. Try all of this from your local machine and from an outside source to eliminate possible issues with external firewalls or routing.
I’d put all this in a comment but I don’t have enough brownie points yet to comment, sorry. Hope this helps narrow down the issue.

Thank you for your response, any help is appreciated as I have been at this for many days. Using netcat, I get a timeout, both from local machine and external. The same timeout error is given using curl --verbose site.com 443. I am beginning to think port 443 may not actually be open but I don't know how else to confirm. Any help is greatly appreciated !

Right in that case the weberver is not listening on port 443 (since 127.0.0.1:443 netcat times out connecting).

Thank you, that is my theory as well. I have confirmed that port 443 https is enabled in Windows Firewall, and I also added an inbound rule to explicitly open port 443 to all connections just in case. Is there anything else I should check/do to make sure 443 is truly open. I don't believe I have any other rules that conflict with port 443 but I do no know how to check that.

Ah, forgot it was Windows. One way to check would be to completely disable the firewall temporarily for a minute and test. If you can connect, its windows firewall, if you still can’t, it’s the web server being misconfigured. If it’s the web server, back to IIS configs. And do every test using https://127.0.0.1 as well as https://LANIP as IIS may be listening in just one IP or interface (actually check that in IIS settings too).
